# Generate number upon macro execution and transfer it to another table where there is no existing data in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to generate a number in A1 in Sheet1 every time the Makro is executed. The number is a combination of the date and a number to be incremented. The final number is to be transferred to Sheet2 in column A where there is not yet data (in this case A1>A2>A3>....)

[image: this is my attempt with worksheetfunctions and Serves as a visualization]

And this is my attempt in VBA but it does nothing.

```
Sub incrementInvoiceNumber()
  Dim rng_dest As Range
  Dim i As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = WorksheetFunction.Text(Date, "YYYYMMDD") & WorksheetFunction.Text(Range("A1").Value + 1)
  i = 1
  Set rng_dest = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")
  Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng_dest.Rows(i)) = 0
   i = i + 1
  Loop

 Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not so clear what exactly is making the code not working. I think its that some rages are not called by its parent sheet.

Besides, it's always better to avoid WorksheetFunction if you have VBA function that can do the same thing.

And, finding the last row can be done in a much better way by using `End()` method.

This is how:

```
Sub incrementInvoiceNumber()
    Dim i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = _
        Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") & Format(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value + 1) 'Make sure Sheet1 is the sheet with the value. Fix it if otherwise

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Then i = i + 1
        .Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

`Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)` means the cell that you will reach if you start from the last cell in column A ("A1048576") and press Ctrl + Up Arrow.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will keep in mind to refrain from using worksheet functions :).